# Cannot exit fullscreen on Spotify

Tags: fullscreen, spotify

I had Spotify running in fullscreen mode on a second monitor when I closed it and unplugged my laptop.  Now Spotify starts in fullscreen mode and I am unable to exit it. Using <kbd>F11</kbd> just skips the current song.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, how about Alt+Tab, or to kill application by System Monitor > Processes?

Comment: alt+tab takes me back to whatever I was on last, spotify is still in fullscreen and I can see it behind the activities bar. I can close out of it just fine by pressing the windows key and clicking the X, but whenever I relaunch it, it goes back to full screen.

Comment: Alt+Space: you can bring the window menu, Alt+drag: you can drag windows which you can't grab the window bar. For this problem, someone already resolved by deleting $HOME/.config/spotify

Comment: If using wmctrl make sure of the right usage of the "-r" argument. -r <string match the window title>. If you are listening to music, the title of the spotify window changes changes to "artist - song title" which leaves the command wmctrl -r spotify -b toggle,fullscreen
not finding the right window.

Comment: Try to use `wmctrl` if you dont know what the process is called you can first do `wmctrl -l`

Answer (score 83):

### Minimally invasive fix without dependencies for simple copy & paste - 2023

#### Regular installation (RPM / DEB)

1. Close Spotify
2. Run `sed -i "/\b\(app.window.position\)\b/d" -- $HOME/.config/spotify/prefs`
3. Run Spotify

#### Flatpak installation

1. Close Spotify
2. Run `sed -i "/\b\(app.window.position\)\b/d" -- $HOME/.var/app/com.spotify.Client/config/spotify/prefs`
3. Run Spotify

#### Snap installation

1. Close Spotify
2. Run `sed -i "/\b\(app.window.position\)\b/d" -- $HOME/snap/spotify/current/.config/spotify/prefs`
3. Run Spotify

*(Thanks to @MrFuppes for the Snap instructions)*

Source for sed command: [How to remove lines from the text file containing specific words through terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354993/how-to-remove-lines-from-the-text-file-containing-specific-words-through-termina/355007#355007)

Btw: This is not Ubuntu-Specific, I'm on Fedora Linux.

Comment: also works with the snap version; `sed -i "/\b\(app.window.position\)\b/d" -- $HOME/snap/spotify/current/.config/spotify/prefs`

Answer (score 10):

I've had this issue for a while now, and @Sadaharu Wakisaka commented that for someone, it's already resolved by deleting `$HOME/.config/spotify`, but for me, with the snap version, I had to delete `$HOME/snap/spotify/current/.config/spotify` while Spotify was not running, and then sign in again

**EDIT!**

There's a better solution which solves the issue without deleting the file. Do not delete the file unless no other solution works for you

Comment: No need to kill everything with fire, just remove the lines containing `app.window.position` from from the `prefs` file. See my answer on how to do that with sed. Should work with snaps, too, if you adjust the file path.

Comment: This action will erase ALL configuration for the app. Most likely, none of your shortcuts will work afterward!

Comment: This is a panic response and shouldn't have as many upvotes as it does. 

Reluctant to give it a downvote as it will fix the issue, but it will likely cause other issues too.

Comment: I've updated my answer to avoid people preferring my solution, because you're completely right, @Tisch, it was a "panic" solution which did work

Answer (score 7):

[I pulled out a simple script that can toggle fullscreen on Spotify.](https://gist.github.com/KokoseiJ/c5802d15dd1ad02dacb772eade312021) It uses `wmctrl`, but since the other answer uses window title to specify the window and it didn't work out in my system, I used `xwininfo` to manually resolve a window ID of Spotify.

It's a one-liner, which is following:

```bsh
xwininfo -root -tree | grep '("spotify" "Spotify")' | grep -oE '(0x[0-9a-z]{7,8})' | xargs -I % wmctrl -i -r % -b toggle,fullscreen
```

It grabs info of every window on system, grab spotify's window ID using couple `grep` commands, and shoves it into wmctrl command.

It should work regardless of distro as long as you have `xwininfo` installed, I use this on Fedora Cinnamon spin.

Comment: I also needed to install wmctrl(`sudo apt install wmctrl`) but this answer did help. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Please follow the steps below to exit *Full Screen* on Spotify:

Open a Terminal window and install *wmctrl*:

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

While Spotify is running, pause the music and run the following command:

```
wmctrl -r spotify -b toggle,fullscreen
```

It should go back to windowed mode and you may keep playing your music ;)

Comment: For me the `toggle` option did not work, but `wmctrl -r spotify -b remove,fullscreen` did, using Ubuntu 21.04 with spotify snap package.

Comment: Worked for similar issue with Plex Media Player. Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 2):

It depends if you have installed spotify through snap. In my case, I had installed spotify in snap. In this case:

1. Goto spotify in snap folder. Notice **the number 42** may change so use ls to know what number is in your case.

   ```
   cd snap/spotify/42/.config/spotify
   ```
2. Then edit the preferences file:

   ```
   gedit prefs
   ```
3. Set the number for app.window.position.width to a different value. It worked for me the value as reported in this thread [Full-screen-under-Ubuntu-18-04](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Full-screen-under-Ubuntu-18-04/td-p/4537645) which is `1320`.

   ```
   app.window.position.width=1320
   ```
4. Save changes and start spotify. It should not be in full screen.

Comment: `wmctrl` did not work for me. This worked like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, Spotify version 1.1.55.498.gf9a83c60.

Comment: Isn't their an "auto" value?

Comment: @MitaliCyrus That is because it sounds like the app isn't in fullscreen. It is just configured to be bigger than the screen. This can be fixed with `wmctrl` but with a different sub-command.

Answer (score 1):

I just went into my files, showed hidden files, went into the Spotify folder, opened prefs under .config/spotify and changed app.window.position.saved=true to app.window.position.saved=false after the other things didn't helpt. idk but it seems to have worked

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an app or extension that forces applications to open full-screen? I use one on my Fedora 24 for WXChat that lets me put apps on a specific screen and position, including full screen.
one-liner solution:

sed -i -E -e 's|(^app.window.position.saved)=true|\1=false|' 
-e 's|(^app.window.position.height)=.*|\1=920|' 

-e 's|(^app.window.position.width)=.*|\1=1200|' 
.var/app/com.spotify.Client/config/spotify/prefs